# If $\langle x \rangle =_{df} H(\{x\})$ with $H(S) , (S $ a set $)$ as defined below , how can $\langle x \rangle$ have more than $3$ elements?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, definition, finitely-generated

Def. of $H(S) :$ $H(S) = \{g\in G \mid \exists n\in \mathbb N , \exists \{g_1, g_2,...
g_n\}\subseteq S\cup S^{-1} , g = g_1 ...g_n\}$.

Note : it can be shown that $H(S)$ is simply the same set as $\langle S \rangle$.

---

Context : group theory.

The reference I am using is Reversat & Bigonnet , *Algèbre pour la licence* ( Undergraduate Abstract Algebra).

The authors propose a ***formal definition of $\langle x \rangle$ as the result of applying to a singleton $\{x\}$ the general definition of  a set H(S)*** such that :

$H(S) :$ $H(S) = \{g\in G \mid \exists n\in \mathbb N , \exists \{g_1, g_2,...
g_n\}\subseteq S\cup S^{-1} , g = g_1 ...g_n\}$.

In words ( as  understand it),  $H(S)$ is the set of all $g_{\in G}$ such that , for som $n$, $g$ is the product of $n$ factors coming from an $n$-elements subset of $S\cup S^{-1}$ , with $S^{-1}=$ the set of the inverses of the elements of $S$.

I know that if $x$ is a member of some group $G$ , $\langle x \rangle$ can have more than $3$ elements.

But, when I try to apply the formal definition, I get ( apparently) a contrary result.

If $S = \{x\}$ , then $S\cup S^{-1} = \{x, x^{-1}\}$

A finite ( necessarily finite) subset of $S\cup S^{-1}$ is

- $\emptyset$
- $\{x\}$
- $\{x^{-1}\}$
- $\{x, x^{-1}\}$

The products ( with a finite number of factors) that can be made out of these subsets are : $x$ , $x^{-1}$ , $xx^{-1}$.

So it seems that I  get $\langle x \rangle = \{e, x,x^{-1} \}$.

> **How to escape this conclusion? What mistake do I make in the application to $S= \{x\}$ of the general definition of $H(S)$.**
>
> If the factors that " compose" $g\in H(\{x\})$ must come ( in this particular case)  from a subset of $\{x, x^{-1}\}$ , how can $g$ be the product of more that $2$ factors?

Comment: You're leaving out a lot of other elements, like $xx$, $xxx$, $xxx^{-1]$ etc.

Comment: Your definition of $H(S)$ is the source of the problem I reckon. It has to be written as $\exists y_1\dots\exists y_n$ or it is not properly specified- there's more to this than just specifying the set of $y_i$.